# VB.Net Issue with Chart Drawing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, charts

Is there a way in VB.Net to Fix the Width of the Chart Grids?
The chart below explains the issue more; the Chart Grids Edge Keep moving left and right (Of course the chart width itself is already Fixed) when Input Data changed; 
I want to keep the width of the GRIDs (Not the Chart) Fixed within the red vertical lines;
Help Appreciated.

[image: Figure Showing the Chart Grid Issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh, figured it out after few hours;
below the code:

```
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).InnerPlotPosition.X = CSng(10 / Chart1.Width) * 100 'Left border
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).InnerPlotPosition.Y = CSng(10 / Chart1.Height) * 100 'Top Border
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).InnerPlotPosition.Width = CSng((Chart1.Width - 20) / Chart1.Width) * 100
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).InnerPlotPosition.Height = CSng((Chart1.Height - 20) / Chart1.Height) * 100
```

hope it is useful for others...